# Elisp - Function stopping when error is met

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have the following snippet of code:

```
(defun my-move-line-below ()
 (interactive)
 (let ((point-from-start (- (point) (line-beginning-position))))
  (kill-whole-line)
  (next-line)
  (move-beginning-of-line nil)
  (yank)
  (previous-line)
  (goto-char (+ (line-beginning-position) point-from-start))))
```

What it does is it moves the current line below the the next one. It works well, but problem is that when EOF is reached, the function stops after next-line, thus killing the line without yanking it back.

I know I could solve this by checking the line number and such, but I wonder if it is possible to just ignore the error and continue the execution of the function.

Comment: `C-h f next-line` says: "This function is for interactive use only;
in Lisp code use `forward-line' instead.".  Same for `previous-line`.  Also, rather than kill&yank (which affect the `kill-ring` and the clipboard), you should use `delete-and-extract-region` and `insert`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think replacing `(next-line)` with

```
(ignore-errors (next-line))
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out, there is a ready-made function for that, `C-x C-t`, although it does not remember the point position after transposition.